# How to get the id of table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table as,

```
<table border="1" id="hide">
        <tr id="col">
            <th>Company Ticker</th>
            <th>SubordinationID</th>
            <th>Currency</th>
            <th>ThreeM</th>
            <th>SixM</th>
            <th>NineM</th>
            <th>OneY</th>
            <th>TwoY</th>
            <th>FiveY</th>
            <th>TenY</th>
            <th>FifteenY</th>
            <th>TwentyY</th>
            <th>ThirtyY</th>
        </tr>
        <%
            Connection connection2 = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            Statement statement2 = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet2 = statement
                    .executeQuery("select * from CDSCURVE");
        %>

        <tr id="row">
            <td id="a">Dummy1</td>
            <td id="b">Dummy2</td>
            <td id="c">Dummy3</td>
            <td id="d">Dummy4</td>
            <td id="e">Dummy5</td>
            <td id="f">Dummy6</td>
            <td id="g">Dummy7</td>
            <td id="h">Dummy8</td>
            <td id="i">Dummy9</td>
            <td id="j">Dummy0</td>
            <td id="k">Dummy11</td>
            <td id="l">Dummy12</td>
            <td id="m">Dummy13</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

here i want to get the value of id attribute named (a,b,c,d,e,f,g...) in a variable.
Need help to create jquery function

one more thing i have multiple rows with different id's then how can retrieve id of the columns specific to that row.

Comment: $("table").attr('id'). If you have only one table in the page

Comment: Use this reference [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
    var id = [];
    var values = [];
    $("#row > td").each(function(index){
       id.push($(this).attr("id")); // [a,b,c,....]
       values.push($(this).text()); //[ Dummy1, Dummy2, Dummy3, Dummy4,..]
    });
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E7TN4/1/)

Comment: @Azuu Have u seen the fiddle demo?

Comment: @Azuu whether fiddle demo works correctly and matches with your requirement ? plz post the error if any

Comment: its working.. but i am getting the row id dynamically and i have that in a variable then how will i put it in above function???

Comment: @Azuu After rendering the rows, place the above in appropriate function, `one change : $("#"+variable > td")`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27621/discussion-between-karthick-k-and-azuu)

Comment: how can i attach html to the div tag in jquery.?

Answer (score 2):

You can push all your ids into an array like this:

```
var IdArray = [];
$("#row").find("td").each(function(){
    IdArray.push(this.id); 
});
```

---

Other way is using [map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
var IdArray = $("#row").find("td").map(function() { 
                  return this.id; 
              }).get(); //["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m"]
```

Comment: If the IDs need to be all together for some reason, you could do `IdArray.join()` and convert the array to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Go through jquery selectors.

You should try something like this

```
var arrayVar = new Array();
$("#hide").find("td").each(function(){
alert($(this).attr("id"));
arrayVar.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: this does not actually accomplish what the poster asked ;)

Comment: @nandu using this code it reads all the id from table but i have multiple rows with a diiferent id's i want to retreive the id of column of that specific row.

Comment: @Azuu do you know which row it would be?? .. if you did .. you can use the nth element selector of jquery.  I can give you the code if required. Let me know

Comment: yupp i have the id of that variable stored in a variable

Comment: @Azuu then just replace $("#hide") with $("#"+whatever_the_id_is)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#hide tr td").click(function () {
                var id = this.id;
                alert($("#" + id).html());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var result = []
var id = $('#row').children();
for (i=0, i < id.length(), i++){
    r = id[i].attr('id')
    result.push(r)
};
final = result.join('');
```

it might be to much tequila this night